# 10 Second delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

Instead of slow, I'd like to add a 10 second delay here.

```
 $(this).animate({backgroundColor:"#d3d0d0"},'slow');
```

My coding skills really suck, so it would be great if anyone could provide
some working lines of code. Thank you.

Comment: Usually asking for others to write code for you is bad form. Also, this answer should be easily google-able. I didn't downvote you, but that's probably why.

Comment: As I said I totally suck at coding, so what's wrong with asking people for some help and some short lines of code? I don't get it. Seriously. :hugs @Metagrapher

Comment: There is a delay function in jQuery, which in my opinion should have been the accepted answer, and which is the #1 result in the Google query: delay jquery.

Comment: As I said though, I didn't downvote you, but I was trying to help you understand what the probable reason for the event was. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist
 We definitely encourage questions here, but we are also community moderated and many generally don't like questions asking for code and asking for things that can be easily researched before posting. Cheers and welcome!

Comment: Found a solution meanwhile, but thanks though for coming back with these helpful lines, really appreciate it. I'm sorta new to all this computer stuff, maybe one day I'll be a little more quicker in my analog brain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $this = $(this);
setTimeout(function() {
    $this.css({backgroundColor: "#d3d0d0"}).fadeOut("slow");
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Superb, works great. And how can I tell it to fade out `slow`? @Barmar

Comment: Again:Thank you very much. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Just use [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) function

```
$(this).delay(10000).animate({backgroundColor:"#d3d0d0"}, 'slow');
```